# Joining groups of strings to create a compound string in java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create an activation to be used in activating my android app that looks like this xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx now I have written a random alphanumeric key generator method as show here

```
    // function to generate a random string of length n
   public static String generateRandom(int n)
    {
    // chose a Character random from this String
    String AlphaNumericString = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
            + "0123456789" + "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz";
    // create StringBuffer size of AlphaNumericString
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // generate a random number between
        // 0 to AlphaNumericString variable length
        int index = (int)(AlphaNumericString.length() * Math.random());

        // add Character one by one in end of sb
        sb.append(AlphaNumericString .charAt(index));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

this part is supposed to generate a unique set of alphanumeric keys of length supplied within the parameters in this case i will use 4.

I also have another method that calls the generateRandom() four times to get the four sets of the key and then join them together separating them with a hyphen - as shown bellow

```
    public static String generateKey(int length){
   StringBuilder key = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i<length; i++){
        if(key.toString().length()==0){
            key.append(generateRandom(4));
        }else if(key.toString().length() % 4==0){
           key.append("-");
       }else{
           key.append(generateRandom(4));
       }
    }
   return key.toString();
}
```

Now when I run this program i expect the output to look like this xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx but what I get looks like this xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx What could I be doing wrong or how can I achieve my target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by calling **key.append(generateRandom(4));** within the loop and adding the hyphen on every count that is not the last. Doing that avoids having an append at the end of the generated string.

```
public static String generateKey(int length){
           StringBuilder key = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i = 0; i<length; i++){
                key.append(generateRandom(4));
                if (i<length-1)
                    key.append("-");
            }
           return key.toString();
}
```

Comment: You should generate random number based on length not static

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String generateKey(int length)
{
        StringBuilder key = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = 0; i<length-1; i++)
        {
                key.append(generateRandom(4));
                key.append("-");
        }
        key.append(generateRandom(4));
        
        return key.toString();
    }
```

for each part, add '-', without checking (if...), and the last one do it after the loop.

Comment: You should generate random number based on length not static

Comment: @chandmohd , the length is the number of  4 successive chars like this length = 3 , so the result is XXXX-XXXX-XXXX ,  so 4 is static, and the number of parts (blocks) is dynamiques.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String generateKey(int length){
        StringBuilder key = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i<length; i++){
            String op = generateRandom(length);
            if (i == length-1)
                key.append(op);else key.append(op).append("-");
        }
        return key.toString();
    }
```